# Specify Culture Name for Resource File in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, culture, corrupt, resource-file

when i try to create a resource file named `Labels.resx` it works fine and a `Labels.designer.cs` being created well, but when i try to create another resource file for a specific locale like `Labels.en-US.resx` the resource file gets corrupted and the designer will be empty!

**[Edit from comments]**: The resource generator specified for the .resx file is `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator`

whats wrong with it? am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: try "Labels.en.resx"

Comment: It didn't make change @levent

Comment: Can you check in properties of the resx file what tool is specified there? I think you can also `Run custom tool` and see if any error shows in output (most probable cause of `designer.cs` file remaining empty)

Comment: it's `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator` @Alexei

Comment: @Hooman - is there a particular reason to use `GlobalResourceProxyGenerator`? I have always generated resource files using `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` and had no problems.

Comment: yes, the problem was because of that! thank you for the guide @Alexei

Comment: @Hooman - I have added used resource generator in the question to make it useful for future viewers. You can accept this edit (and enhance it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, the solution is to use another resource generator:

```
PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
```

instead of

```
GlobalResourceProxyGenerator
```